# C++ get time with milliseconds

Tags: visual-c++, datetime

I'm working on a project with MPI and I want to write a logging system.

I want to ask you guys what should I use to get the **current time in milliseconds** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the current *local* date and time, call the [`GetLocalTime` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338.aspx).

If you want the current date and time in *UTC format*, call the [`GetSystemTime` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390.aspx).

Both of these functions accept a single parameter, a pointer to a [`SYSTEMTIME` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950.aspx), which they fill in with the current date and time information.

After calling the function, you can read the time out of that structure. The member you're looking for would be `wMilliseconds`, which returns the current millisecond (somewhere between 0 and 999).

Sample code:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st);
std::cout << std::setw(2) << st.wHour << ':'
          << std::setw(2) << st.wMinute << ':'
          << std::setw(2) << st.wSecond << '.'
          << std::setw(3) << st.wMilliseconds << '\n';
```

Answer (score 3):

The MPI routine `MPI_Wtime` returns time in seconds, but usually has milisecond resolution.  Call `MPI_Wtick` to make sure it turns 10e-3 or less.